# Views exposed taxonomy hierarchy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a taxonomy with 4 categories; each category has child-categories beneath them.

This taxomony term is exposed in a view filter, but I get a combination of the parent and child categories in the resulting dropdown list options. What I actually want is just the parent-categories listed and not the child-categories.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind!

I just discovered the "limit list to selected items" check box which solved my problem.
It does mean I have to manually select the taxonomy terms I want visible. So, it's not a fully automated solution but it will do for now.